# Fibonacci Sequence golden ratio big O proof

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, fibonacci-numbers

Fibonacci numbers are defined as $F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1$ and $F(i) = F(i-1) + F(i-2)$ for $i≥2$.

$Θ = (1 + \sqrt{5}) / 2$.

$F(x) = x^2 - x- 1$.

1) Show that $F(Θ)$ = 0 and that $F'(x) > 0$ for any integer $x≥ 1$. For any $a, b$ such that $1 ≤ a < Θ < b$ we have  $a + 1>a^2$ and $b + 1 < b^2$.

2) Prove that  for any $a,b$ such that $1 ≤ a < Θ < b$ we have $F(n) = O(b^n)$ and that $F(n) = Ω(a^n).$

My initial thought was to look at the theta and find $c2$ and $c1$ for it, however I am lost as what values of $a$ and $b$ am I looking for? Any help to steer me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I think that the notation is confusing. If $F(n)$ is the $n$-th Fibonacci number then $F(n)\not=n^2-n+1$!

Comment: On formatting: It's much easier to put \$ signs around entire expressions. E.g. \$F(x)=x^2+x+1.\$   It will keep  an expression within one line, and looks better. Punctuation can go inside \$ ...... I usually leave them out until I'm done writing. Then I have to re-read it to put the \$  in which means I catch most of my errors. My edit was for formatting, some minor typos, a major typo: a mis-placed ) in $(1+\sqrt 5)/2,$ and periods at ends of sentences.... BTW \; gives a bit of space, e.g. $\sqrt 7\;x$ compared to $\sqrt 7x$.... And \quad gives  a chunk $\quad$ of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. As regards 1) by solving the quadratic equation  $q(x):=x^2 - x - 1=0$, we obtain that the roots are
$$x_{\pm}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$
Hence $q(x)=(x-x_+)(x-x_-)$ and it follows that $q(x)>0$ iff $x>x_+$ or $x<x_-$.

For 2), note that from $x_\pm^{n}=x_\pm^{n-1}+x_\pm^{n-2}$, we get
$$F(n)=\frac{x_+^n-x_-^n}{\sqrt{5}}.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I sere that you obtain the two roots from golden ratio(that was originally my first thought) and that $f(x)$ > iif x > (1+$\sqrt{5})/2$)  or x < (1- $\sqrt{5})/2$). However I am lost as to how this leads us to A and B. We know that Θ is one of those roots and that 1≤a<Θ<b. In that case the other root holds no value as only positive integers are allowed in  $1≤a<Θ<b$

Comment: In that case I believe the c1 and c2 values would be a and b, where a is bounded by 1 to 1.6ish and b must be greater than 1.6ish.

Comment: @skryt If $b>Θ=x_+$ then $q(b)>0$, that is $b^2>b+1$. For $O(b^n)$ show that $F(n)/b^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense now.